# How do I tell if my Samsung Galaxy uses XEU or BTU etc...?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-a5

i'm wondering how to tell the difference between a Samsung Galaxy A5 2017 flashed with something like XEU or one with BTU. That is if it's already installed and if I don't know what type it is.

Any answers are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**XEU** or **BTU** (...) are Samsung CSC codes. CSC stands for *Country Specific Code*. It is unique for each country or region or network carrier. This [website](https://www.androidsage.com/2017/07/12/list-of-samsung-galaxy-country-specific-product-code-csc-and-country-region/) lists them all.

So to check which CSF file your Samsung device has, try the following:

- Dial *#1234#
- Go to `Settings > About phone > Software information` then you should see something like `Service provider SW version`, see screenshot below: Here AIO is the CSC.

[image]

- Download Phone Info app from Google Play Store

Comment: XEU and BTU are both UK types. XEU European Union